# Printing in Material That Is Safe to Drink From/Dishwasher/Microwave Safe

Tags: filament-choice, food

I'm looking to get printed a design for a coffee mug, which needs to be dishwasher safe, microwavable safe, and safe to drink out of. What kind of filament or equipment would give these properties? If not, is there a company that offers such services?

Comment: about 9 years ago there was one doing their own 3d printed ceramic+glaze mugs but they did not accept custom one-off designs and I do not believe they achieved dishwasher safe - glaze and fire process after 3D print did not cover everything.  All other info I have might be obtained by searching the nets.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because recommendation questions are not allowed on the stack.

Comment: PETG meets the requirements for dishwasher safe and safe to drink out of, but if you're not careful in the microwave I think you'd get it hot enough to damage it. (FWIW I have PETG cold beverage cups that have been through many tens of dishwasher cycles with no problem.) Kilisi's answer is probably what you really want.

Comment: @Trish: The actual question part of the question body, "Does anyone have any experience of using a filament/equipment that would do this?", is on-topic, and I think the question is okay to answer regarding what technologies would be appropriate and how to look for a service offering them, without recommendations of a particular service to use. "There don't seem to be any services doing this at present" also seems like a reasonable thing to put in an answer, if that's the case.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE only if rewritten that way

Comment: OK, I've made an edit that I feel is still faithful to OP's intent while focusing on what's in-scope and removing the apparent shopping question part.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE The "suggest a service" part is the disallowable part: it asks for a recommendation. But "What type of filament or equipment" would work.

Comment: @Trish: Was "are there services of this sort?" inappropriate even?

Comment: Yes, that part is readable as "recommend me a service"

Comment: IMHO, this question was fine at edit #2, there was no (direct) request for a recommendation, merely an inquiry as to whether anyone had experience. The subsequent edits appear to have put words into the OP's mouth, which is not really correct nor fair. The OP's latest edit #5 *has* now (re-)introduced the recommendation request (which isn't *strictly* allowed). I believe that the question should be rolled back to edit #2 and then left as it is.

Comment: @Greenonline I’m unable to find a single company that does this; it’s not like I’m asking for a recommendation as to what works well and what doesn’t. The closest thing I am able to find about this is to purchase a WASP clay extruder but I still need a kiln and have to look up the specifics of that. I’m looking for comments like use PETG, upload your STL file here and use this filament, and stuff like that. I would appreciate it if new comments were only about this subject. I think it would be beneficial to even delete the comments that are not about this subject above

Answer (score 2):

You need to find a company like this.
[image: Image from Istock]

Or you could 3D print clay yourself, there are clay 3D printers online.

Comment: Do you have any ideas of what company might do this? I have been searching but cannot find anything out there

Comment: Depends on your budget

Comment: Something that a high school student could afford if they really wanted it

Comment: That means nothing to me. Not even sure what highschool is, but when I was in school I could afford a coffee mug from a $2 shop once in a while I guess.

Comment: "High School" US term for grades 9-12 for students (roughly) aged 14-18. 12th grade ("Senior" or "High School Senior") is the last year of federally mandated education. After successfully completing all 12 years, people move on to secondary education ("college"), the military, or civilian work force.

Comment: The problem is quantifying "what a highschool student could afford" - is that 5\$ or 50\$ or 500 \$? All of those are reasonable for different high schools in different areas....

Comment: Is there something that does this for around those prices?

Comment: What prices? For 500 I can hire a master potter to make a all series unique mugs, for 50 I can order some customized mugs on a basic model from a print shop. For 5 I can get one or two mugs from IKEA.